# Python: What does %s do here?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

What does the `%s` do here at the end of the chrome_path variable? Without it the function can "not locate runnable browser"

```
import webbrowser as wb
chrome_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
url = "www.google.com"
wb.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

Comment: The URL (well, it's not really a URL) is substituted in in place of the `%s` placeholder, making a command line that will open the URL in the browser.

Comment: I did read about this substitution on that post but I don't understand what the placeholder is for

Comment: Well, if you were going to open a Web site in Chrome from the command line, you would type e.g. `chrome http://www.google.com/` right? Clearly `webbrowser` is putting together a command line of this sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trace through [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/webbrowser.py#L35) it looks like the library can run in two ways here; `wb.get()` expects either a browser name or a shell command with a `%s` placeholder.

The browser name can be a human readable name that is configured elsewhere.

Accepting a shell command allows more complicated commands, or for the use of browsers not recognised by the library.

If you give a shell command, the `url` given when you call `.open(url)` is substituted for the `%s`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and clarification I understand now that the url is substituted into the %s. Thanks